# Schwarz-Pick Lemma from upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f: UHP \to D_1(0)$ map the upper half of the complex plane to the unit disk. It is known that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for real $z$ and also at infinity. Furthermore, consider that $f$ is meromorphic in the UHP. Then, by the Maximus Modulus Principle one concludes that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all the domain.

I am trying to show that

$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)-f(\omega)}{1-f(z)\bar{f(\omega)}}*\left(\frac{z-\omega}{z-\bar{\omega}}\right)^{-1}$$

is also bounded as $|g(z)|\leq 1$, in the UHP and for any $\omega$ (parameter) also in the UHP.

I know that $g(z)$ is meromorphic in the UHP, and if I managed to show that it is bounded in the boundaries, I would use the MMP again to generalize for the whole UHP. Both when $z$ is real or infinity, I was able to show that the second term is $\leq 1$. However, the term with $f(z)$ seems a bit harder to analyse. How can I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the Schwarz lemma. Let $U$ denote the upper half plane and $D$ the unit disk.

Let $w$ be a fixed point in the upper half plane. The mapping $\phi_1(z) = \dfrac{z-w}{z-\bar w}$ is conformal with $\phi_1 : U \to D$ and $\phi_1(w) = 0$. Thus $f \circ \phi_1^{-1} : D \to D$ is analytic with $f \circ \phi_1^{-1}(0) = f(w)$.

The mapping $\phi_2(\xi) = \dfrac{\xi - f(w)}{1 - \xi \overline{f(w)}}$ is conformal with $\phi_2 : D \to D$ and $\phi_2(f(w)) = 0$.  Consequently $h = \phi_2 \circ f \circ \phi_1^{-1} : D \to D$ is analytic with $h(0) = 0$. The Schwarz lemma guarantees $|h(\zeta)| \le |\zeta|$ for all $\zeta \in D$. This implies
$$|\phi_2 \circ f(z)| \le |\phi_1(z)|$$ for all $z \in U$, so that
$$\left| \frac{f(z) - f(w)}{1 - f(z)\overline{f(w)}} \right| \le \left|\frac{z-w}{z-\bar w}\right|.$$
That is,

$$|g(z)| = \left| \frac{f(z) - f(w)}{1 - f(z)\overline{f(w)}} \left( \frac{z-w}{z-\bar w} \right)^{-1} \right| \le 1$$ for all $z \in U$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed more elegant than what I was trying to do. Also, I think it should be $f \circ \phi^{-1}(0) = f(\omega$), right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the typo.